# OrderBy method using custom order

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of items and I know I can order them alphabetically by the property name, but how can I order them by the actual value and not the property.

For clarification let's say I have this code:

```
List<string> lstNames = db.TestDB.Where(x => x.TestCode == true).Select(x => x.FavoriteName).ToList();
```

Now I know I can order alphabetically by the `FavoriteName` or vice versa, but for arguments sake let's say the Names that are in the database are `"Nick"`, `"Adam"`, `"Chris"` and if I used the `OrderBy` method:

```
List<string> lstNames = db.TestDB.Where(x => x.TestCode == true).Select(x => x.FavoriteName).OrderBy(x => x.FavoriteName).ToList();
```

this would list the names alphabetically `"Adam"`, `"Chris"`,`"Nick"`, and vice versa with:

```
List<string> lstNames = db.TestDB.Where(x => x.TestCode == true).Select(x => x.FavoriteName).OrderBy(x => x.FavoriteName).OrderByDescending(x => x.FavoriteName).ToList();
```

But what if I wanted to order them as `"Chris"`, `"Adam"`, `"Nick"`?

Basically I am looking for a custom way to order a list by the actual values and not the property name?

Also, these values that are in my database will not be changed and I doubt any will be added/deleted.. so I have also tried putting all of the values into their own list and tried the OrderBy method with that list but it did not work.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: In what way is "Chris", "Adam", "Nick" *in order*?  How do you even define that sorting logic?

Comment: @David I know that that is not in order but is the `OrderBy` and `OrderByDescending` methods the only way to "order" a list?  Maybe I am looking for a different method other than those.. I am just looking for a custom way to put together a list based on values that I want to go first and that I want go to last, not alphabetically

Comment: But what @David is asking and I'm wondering myself is What is it that you want to order by?  Is it completely arbitrary or is there a different field/column that you want to order by?

Comment: @CaseyR It is arbitrary and there is not another field or column that I want to order by

Comment: You do know that telling a program to do something *arbitrary* is not a strong suit of programming languages.  Programs == logic, not random

Comment: @Tommy  okay so honestly I am confused.. just because I do not want to order a list alphabetically or in descending alphabetical order, that makes what I am looking for help on not logical? The reason for me asking this question (and looking back on now should've been more carefully written) is so that other developers could help me brainstorm to finding different ways to order a list

Comment: You need to have "some basis" -  Programs execute a set of rules.  Using your example, what basis is there to have the list in the order you provided?  That is what the top comment means - rules, logic, something to tell the computer to arrange the set by.  You can order by random GUIDs if you so choose, but then your ordering is random. You could order by length of name but again this is a rule.   If you want things to show in a specific order, you either need to hard code that order **OR** have some other property that you can have the program use to determine order.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a custom comparer for sorting:

```
public class MyComparer : IComparer<string>
{
    public int Compare(string stringA, string stringB)
    {
        // your comparison logic
        // return 1 if stringA "is greater than" stringB
        // return -1 if stringA "is less than" stringB
        // return 0 if they are equal
    }
}
```

And use that when ordering:

```
lstNames.OrderBy(x => x, instanceOfMyComparer)
```

The comparison logic which defines your ordering in the example given in the question doesn't really make sense to me.  But that's not particularly important.  Whatever logic you want to use would simply go in that `Compare()` method.

Comment: I think it is important to make it clear that custom comparers and DB don't mix well. If `TestDB` is a `IQueryable<>`...

Comment: @xanatos: Good point.  In the case of the OP's code, it looks like a `.ToList()` is thrown in the mix already.  So a custom comparer would have to be after that operation.

Answer (score 0):

If the ordering is arbitrary but you know what it should be, I'd suggest adding another table to your DB that has the FavoriteName and the order #, join to that and then order the result.

If you don't want to do that in the DB, you can accomplish the same thing by hardcoding it, something like this:

```
var nameOrder = new[] { 
    new {Name = "Chris", Order = 1}
    , new {Name = "Adam", Order = 2}
    , new {Name = "Nick", Order = 3}
};

lstNames.Join(nameOrder, lstName => lstName, nameOrd => nameOrd.Name, (Name, nameOrd) => new { Name, nameOrd.Order }).OrderBy(o => o.Order);
```